# Magento 2 how to get custom attribute title and its value in phtml file

Tags: magento2, frontend, custom-attributes

Magento 2 how to get custom attribute title and its value in phtml file.

Comment: which type of custom attribute is it ? product,customer and where do you want to get value ( page )

Comment: Its just custom attribute i need to display its title and value in product detail page..

Comment: what type of attribute is it ? text, select etc ?

Comment: Text attribute...

Comment: http://blog.chapagain.com.np/magento-2-get-attribute-id-name-value-from-attribute-code/  just visit this link

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per your comments, I assume that you are getting the product object.

Then use:

```
$attribute = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('attribute_code');
```

This will give the attribute object, where **`attribute_code`** is the attribute code.

then use the following code to get the **value of attribute** for current product:

```
$attribute->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);
```

and use below code to get the **name (label)** of the attribute:

```
$attribute->getFrontendLabel();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get attribute label and attribute value as below

```
$myAttr = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('my_attribute');

if ($myAttr){

    // Get Value
    $attrValue = $myAttr->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);

    // Get Label
    $attrLabel = $myAttr->getStoreLabel();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Go to :

> Store->Attributes->Product
>
> find your attribute and click to open edit page and select
>   "**Storefront Properties**"

And from there "**Allow HTML Tags on Storefront**" select to **Yes**.

Then on your template you can get value by $product->getYourAttributeCode()

**NOTE** : if your attribute is like **custom_attribute** then your method will be like $product->getCustomAttribute();